# issue rendering a custom shopware block

Tags: shopware6

i''ve crated a new shopware block with 4 images and a text for each of them, i can edit in in shopware experience adding images and texts, but the block is not rendered when i save the layout.
i can only see the html structure of my block but the content is empty.

so i think the error is in my `<pluginRoot>/pluginName/src/Resources/views/storefront/block/sw-cms-block-multicolumn-carousel.html.twig`

```html
{% block sw_cms_block_multicolumn_carousel %}
    <div class="sw-cms-block-multicolumn-carousel data-cms-element-id="{{ element.id }}"">
        <div class="bg-carousel-container">
            <div class="dark-bg">
                <div class="img-carousel">
                    {% set element = block.slots.getSlot('topone') %}
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-text">
                    {% set element = block.slots.getSlot('botone') %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-carousel-container">
            <div class="dark-bg">
                <div class="img-carousel">
                    {% set element = block.slots.getSlot('toptwo') %}
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-text">
                    {% set element = block.slots.getSlot('bottwo') %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-carousel-container">
            <div class="dark-bg">
                <div class="img-carousel">
                    {% set element = block.slots.getSlot('topthree') %}
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-text">
                    {% set element = block.slots.getSlot('botthree') %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

so in this case i think the code can't pick this value: `{% set element = block.slots.getSlot('topone') %}`

can someone help me to render this block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` call assigns a value to a variable, but doesn't output anything. You're assigning `element` over and over again without ever doing anything with it.

After assigning `element` each time, you would usually want to include a template with element type specific markup.

```html
{% set element = block.slots.getSlot('topone') %}
<div data-cms-element-id="{{ element.id }}">
    {% sw_include "@Storefront/storefront/element/cms-element-" ~ element.type ~ ".html.twig" ignore missing %}
</div>
```

If you don't want to include the default element templates, [have a look at the `cms-element-*` templates](https://github.com/shopware/platform/tree/trunk/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/element) to get an idea what they do with the data assigned to `element`. If you're in a `dev` environment, for debugging purposes, you can also use `{{ dump(element) }}` to output the raw values of its properties.